# PDB file and error handling?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms, exception

We have a windows form application running across different customers, when they get errors we log into a database & using that stack information that is logged, we correct the issue.

However there are issues that occur only in production, the stack shows for example

> CalculateTotals(method name) :NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to instance of an object.

The CalculateTotals is a method name, that has lots of sub-method calls & more lines, i am not able to get the exact line # of the code where it fails.

My application's PDB file is not sent to customers (when they do installation),

how do i keep a copy of that .PDB file (may be in a remote location and 
not make it part of installation) and use that to 
debug the errors & get the exact line?

Comment: A remote location would be tough; your customers would have to allow that traffic through their firewall. Why don't you want to include the PDBs with the installation?

Comment: Can we include PDBs part of actual production releases?

Comment: You might want to try using intellitrace instead http://www.wintellect.com/cs/blogs/jrobbins/archive/2009/10/19/vs-2010-beta-2-intellitrace-in-depth-first-look.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You can include the pdb-files in release if you want to, but you can also use **IntelliTrace** to debug data from production in Visual Studio.

In short, IntelliTrace:

> IntelliTrace plays a role similar to that of a black box in a plane. It keeps track of important points in your programs execution and allow you to play back what happened at those points at a later time.

Have a look at these blog posts:

- [Running IntelliTrace on Applications in Production](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2012/03/16/running-intellitrace-on-applications-in-production.aspx)
- [IntelliTrace - what and how](http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/intellitrace-%E2%80%93-what-and-how).

And of course, you can search the web and find more about IntelliTrace.

Comment: IntelliTrace heavily affects the process, much like a debugger does, and more.

Comment: @HansPassant I'm not quite sure if you're saying that IntelliTrace is bad or not(?). Yes, it can potentially affect the process heavily if you use the *Events and Calls* mode (I'm no expert). But nevertheless, you could still use it for a limited period to trace a defect down and fix it, right?

Answer (score 1):

You will only get line number info in the exception's stack trace when the CLR can find the PDB file at runtime.  You are making this difficult by wanting to do this from a remote location but it is not impossible.  The underlying API that the CLR uses is DIA (Debug Interface Access) which in turn uses the Debug API.

You'd have to setup the machine the same way you'd setup a debug session to have the debugger use a symbol server.  Requirements are that you first setup a symbol server that can be accessed across the Internet, similar to the Microsoft Symbol Server.  Then set the _NT_SYMBOL_PATH environment to reference that server.  The core MSDN Library page that describes this [is here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681416%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  Beware that this is *not* easy to troubleshoot if it doesn't work.

An entirely different approach is that you create a minidump from the crashed process.  You'll need to pinvoke MiniDumpWriteDump().  Beware that a good minidump for a .NET process is not very mini, you'll need the plumbing to have enough storage and somehow get it to your machine.